# Does async programming mean multi-threading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, asynchronous

lets talk about JavaScript code which has `setInterval` methods every `2` sec.

I also have a `onblur` animation event for some control.

In a case where `onblur` occurs (+ animation), I might get the `setInterval` function.

**Question**:
Does async programming mean multi-threading? (in any way?)

Comment: No, asynchronicity (ism?) does *not* require parallelism.

Comment: under the covers there are threads, but as a programmer/language consumer it's not.

Comment: @Jason there are no threads under the cover. Or at least there don't have to be.

Comment: @Jason: there doesn't have to be more than one thread under the covers either.

Comment: not that i don't believe you, but, cite please.  i assumed the various javascript runtimes used multithreading to produce asynchronous behavior.

Comment: am i reading this wrong - it looks like the mozilla js engine employs multiple threads, i can only assume the others do as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JSRuntime

"Only one thread may use a JSContext at a time. In a JS_THREADSAFE build, multiple threads may run JavaScript code concurrently in the same JSRuntime, but each such thread must have its own JSContext."

Comment: You are reading that wrong.  Note the two important caveats: first, you must be building is a JS_THREADSAFE environment, and even then, only one thread per JsContext object.  So each individual instance of a javascript context is still singles-threaded.  That looks more like one thread per tab/iframe handling, per *context*.  Meanwhile, the V8 engine (the javascript behind Chrome) is completely single-threaded, and Node.JS makes a huge deal about that: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: Was the .NET tag added accidentally? It seems like the .NET tag isn't relevant to this question (I don't see any .NET Framework content in the post),.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

No.  It means literally what it means-- asynchronous.  Understanding the difference between asynchronous programming and thread-based programming is critical to your success as a programmer.

In a traditional, non-threaded environment, when a function must wait on an external event (such as a network event, a keyboard or mouse event, or even a clock event), the program must *wait* until that event happens.

In a multi-threaded environment, many individual threads of programming are running at the same time.  (Depending upon the number of CPUs and the support of the operating system, this may be literally true, or it may be an illusion created by sophisticated scheduling algorithms).  For this reason, multi-threaded environments are difficult and involve issues of threads locking each other's memory to prevent them from overrunning one another.

In an asychronous environment, a single process thread runs all the time, but it may, for event-driven reasons (and that is the key), switch from one function to another.  When an event happens, *and when the currently running process hits a point at which it must wait for another event*, the javascript core then scans its list of events and delivers the next one, in a (formally) indeterminate (but probably deterministic) order, to the event manager.

For this reason, event-driven, asynchronous programming avoids many of the pitfalls of traditional, multi-threaded programming, such as memory contention issues.  There may still be race conditions, as the order in which events are handled is not up to you, but they're rare and easier to manage.  On the other hand, because the event handler does not deliver events until the currently running function hits an idle spot, some functions can starve the rest of the programming.  This happens in Node.js, for example, when people foolishly do lots of heavy math in the server-- that's best shoved into a little server that node then "waits" to deliver the answer.  Node.js is a great little switchboard for events, but anything that takes longer than 100 milliseconds should be handled in a client/server way.

In the browser environment, DOM events are treated as automatic event points (they have to be, modifying the DOM delivers a lot of events), but even there badly-written Javascript can starve the core, which is why both Firefox and Chrome have these "This script is has stopped responding" interrupt handlers.

Comment: What about ajax calls in jQuery , the server side code do its stuff while my browser keeps do other functions.....?

Comment: Those aren't threads, though.  You've sent a message in your browser-side code to the server.  *When the call returns* is an event, and your code is expected to pick it up and do something with it.  While it's waiting, the eventloop goes to handle other events.  When your event returns, the eventloop gives your callback complete control over the single process thread until you give it up by reaching the end of the callback, doing something that causes the eventloop to progress, or creating a new event.

Comment: a great answer, thanks for explaining that in a reasonably jargon-free manner

Comment: Why "anything that takes longer than 100 milliseconds should be handled in a client/server way"? Ajax calls take more than 100 ms sometimes, and my browser doesn't give me the "This script is has stopped responding" message.

Comment: Trusktr: Because node is single-threaded, you shouldn't use the process you're using to handle requests, to also do heavy programmatic lifting; you shouldn't use the same process to do natural language processing, or image processing; you should do that in child processes.  Each process will take time; every other process will be blocked until its done.  If you do it in child processes, you free your "switchboard" process to handle I/O.

Comment: Ajax calls *are* client/server.

Comment: The event loop is a second thread though behind the scenes - the little man listening for the events. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The concept behind is the same. But today the word "thread" is firmly attached to one specific meaning, so people will misunderstand you when you say "hey but there are many things in progress and they can work almost independently and remember their own stuff". Yes. You could call it multitasking, multiprocessing, multithreading, but each of those are allocated for a specific thing and TECHNICALLY it's not the same. But yes you've found a good connection between two areas and their underlying concept is the same. It is "a kind of" multi-threading.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock 'async event handling' is the inbound side, and 'multi-threading' is one way of handling the outbound side. So I suggest using the term 'async event handling' instead of 'multi-threading' for the 'event loop'. With particular notice that it is the execution environment (client/server, user/computer, or process/process like disk I/O) that makes it async, not necessarily multiple threads used by a single process on your computer (even though that could be one such execution environment).

Comment: The jargon-free-ness of this answer is mesmerizing.

Comment: Just to pick up one one thing as someone who comes from the background of systems programming languages. Synchronization between threads is *not* done by locking *memory*. What you refer to here is mutexes which wrap atomic operations, those operations lock *thread execution*. However it often looks like regions of memory are being locked because you can have multiple mutexes and they are *usually* associated with a particular use/purpose which conceptually stores data in a region of memory. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474689/893254

Comment: By the way, what I take away from this answer is fundamentally this: Your JS code is *probably* executing in a single thread and `await` tells the code interpreter to suspend execution on the currently `await`ing line and go and fetch some tasks from an event queue instead.

Comment: > This happens in Node.js, for example, when people foolishly do lots of heavy math in the server-- that's best shoved into a little server that node then "waits" to deliver the answer. Node.js is a great little switchboard for events, but anything that takes longer than 100 milliseconds should be handled in a client/server way. <

If I understand correctly, this frees up the main server to take more requests, while the little server does the heavy processing. BUT, the total processing time remains the same?

Answer (score 8):

A single threaded event loop is a good example of being asynchronous in a single threaded language.

The concept here is that you attach `doLater` callback handlers to the `eventLoop`. Then the `eventLoop` is just a `while(true)` that checks whether the specific timestamp for each `doLater` handler is met, and if so it calls the handler.

For those interested, here is a naive (and horribly inefficient toy) implementation of a [single threaded event loop in JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/eWteV/5/)

This does mean that without any kind of OS thread scheduler access of your single thread, your forced to busy wait on the `doLater` callbacks.

If you have a `sleep` call you could just do `sleep` until the next `doLater` handler which is more efficient then a busy wait since you deschedule your single thread and let the OS do other things.

Answer (score 4):

1. No asynchronous programming doesn't mean multithreading specifically.
2. For achieving multiple tasks at the same time we use multi-threading and other is event loop architecture in node js.
3. JavaScript is synchronous and single threaded and that is why node js is also single threaded but with event loop node do a non-blocking I/O operations. Node.js uses the libuv library that uses a fixed-sized thread pool that handles the execution of parallel tasks.

Thread is a sequence of code instructions and also the sub unit of process.

In multi-threading, processes have multiple threads.
In single threading, processes have single thread.

Answer (score 2):

Only in the sense that it executes code haphazardly and risks race conditions. You will not get any performance benefits from using timeouts and intervals.

However, HTML5's WebWorkers do allow for real multithreading in the browser:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest you to read these 2 articles that completely explain how async tasks run in js. and what are  the differences between handling job with promise or using web workers.

https://blog.devgenius.io/the-difference-between-async-and-threading-45235ebe253d
https://blog.devgenius.io/async-vs-threading-javascript-web-workers-cecb0115d097

in summary async tasks not running in separate thread they are running in main thread but event loop handle this async mechanism, if you want to experience multi-threading in js you can using web workers.

Answer (score -4):

If there is a callback, something has to call it.  The units of execution are threads & so, yes, some other thread has to call the callback, either directly or by queueing up some asynchronous procedure call to the initiating thread.

Comment: It's perfectly possible for the _same single thread_ to call the callback later.

Comment: @Raynos how?  If one thread directly calls a function, it's just called a 'call'.  If the callback is signaled into the thread on some input loop, something must have queued the callback.  A driver could do this directly, but it's usually a kernel thread.

Comment: By having the entire event loop live in the single thread. Note that the thread can't do any IO then, it can only do asynchronous communication with itself and anything within the single thread. This might be pedantry.

Comment: It's not pedantry, Raynos.  You're right.  It's a single thread of execution, the program pointer is a singleton.  Learning to visualize the event queue and the functions hanging off of it-- and learning to respect that, in event-driven programming the function does *not* return to where it left off-- was the single biggest key to my understanding node.js.

Comment: I think we're all arguing the same point from different ends.  From the OS side, there has to be something loading the events onto the queue.  In that respect, 'Does Async programming means - multi Threading ? ( in some way ) ?' the answer has to be yes.  From the js side, things look different.

Comment: No, the answer doesn't have to be multi-threaded.  Do not confuse OS scheduling, programmer-level threading, and asynchronous event handling.  That Way Lies Madness.

Comment: Relevant to this discussion: [The Mozilla Javascript Runtime is now officially single-threaded](http://blog.mozilla.com/luke/2012/01/24/jsruntime-is-now-officially-single-threaded/)

Comment: He's correct in that his point is some other thread *may be* responsible for populating the events in the event loop. But it doesn't always have to be. When it comes to things like networking events, data received from a socket, then of course, another thread is responsible for populating the event queue - even if that is the OS thread, at some level. How the answer has been written is confusing however, and it isn't the case that `await` causes another thread to be spawned.