# typescript: How to check functions are run in parallel

Tags: typescript, promise

I have a simple `for` loop like this:

```
  private async loadImages(urls: string[]): Promise<void> {
    await Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
      this.loadImage(url);
    }));
  }
```

Where `loadImage` prototype is:

```
private async loadImage(url: string): Promise<Image>
```

If my understanding of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/136285) is correct, the `loadImages` function calls `loadImage`(s) in parallel. However looking at chome network tab here is what I see (calls appears to be done cascade, as if one was waiting for the previous one):

[image]

Are there tool to debug what is going on wrong ? is there a simple check to verify if `loadImage` calls are indeed in 'parallel' ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: I have added an comparison with different approaches to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare it with:

```
private async loadImages(urls: string[]): Promise<void> {
  for(url of urls) {
    await this.loadImage(url);
  }
}
```

that call really does wait for each promise to succeed before starting the next and should be far worse in total time to completion.

In a more general sense: You cannot gain infinite concurrency. JavaScript is single-threaded and starting 100 requests in parallel may in fact make your code slower as you have too many requests open at the same time. (You may end up doing a denial of service attack without even realizing it.)

It may make sense to chunk your urls in a set of 5 or 10 urls, and do a `Promise.all` on each chunk. (Or use a Promise libary where you can set the concurrency like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)).

---

I did a testcase but bear in mind that I was using nodejs and not a browser so your mileage may vary. I compared the all in parallel, the iterative and a chunked approach. The all-in-parallel was by far the fastest:

- parallel: 345.985ms
- chunked: 1633.872ms
- iterative: 6681.045ms

---

Here's my code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const parallel = async (urls: string[]): Promise<void> => {
    await Promise.all(
        urls.map(async (url) => {
            return fetch(url);
        })
    );
}

const chunk = <T>(array: T[], size: number = 5): T[][] =>
    Array.from({length: Math.ceil(array.length / size)}, (value, index) => array.slice(index * size, index * size + size));


const chunked = async (urls: string[]): Promise<void> => {
    const chunkedUrls = chunk(urls);


    for (const chunk of chunkedUrls) {
        await Promise.all(chunk.map(url => fetch(url)));
    }
}


const iterative = async (urls: string[]): Promise<void> => {
    for (const url of urls) {
        await fetch(url);
    }
}

const compare = async () => {
    const urls = [...Array(100)].map(() => `http://placekitten.com`);

    console.time('parallel');
    await parallel(urls);
    console.timeEnd('parallel');

    console.time('chunked');
    await chunked(urls);
    console.timeEnd('chunked');

    console.time('iterative');
    await iterative(urls);
    console.timeEnd('iterative')

    return 'completed';
}

compare()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is doing what it's supposed to do. Since javascript is **single threaded** you cannot execute something in parallel.
Nevertheless, promises are **asynchronous** but this is not the same as parallel. If you want to learn more about how asynchronous function work in a single thread I can suggest [this post.](https://medium.com/@francesco_rizzi/javascript-main-thread-dissected-43c85fce7e23)

So `Promise.all` doesn't spawn new threads like you might have thought. Instead, it returns a single promise that resolves when all of the input's promises resolve, or rejects as soon as one of the input's promise rejects.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you can read more about the `Promise.all` function.

---

After ritaj commented on my answer I made a test to be sure:

```js
await Promise.all(
    Array(200).fill(0).map(() => fetch('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films'))
);
```

I watched the thread count of my browser while running this code (sorry herokuapp for 200 requests...). It stayed the same. Therefore the requests must have been executed sequentially.

Comment: None of this is true. Network requests are not executed on the main thread and they can definitely be run in parallel.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963209/does-async-programming-mean-multi-threading) question has a good answer about **async**, **threads** and so on.

Comment: @ritaj are you sure? As far as I know, they are indeed concurrent, but that's not parallel. Why else would the network events look like a "waterfall"?